# Array.map() to Class gives undefined on this

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use the map function of the array to map my data to a specific class. The project is in Angular.

So I do:

```
me.$http({
    url: me.appConfig.api + `customer/${customer.number}/stock/warehouses`,
    method: 'get'
}).then((r: any) => {
    def.resolve(r.data.map(Warehouse));
}).catch(def.reject);
```

Pretty basic so far. Then in my Warehouse class it looks like this:

```
export class Warehouse {
    code: string;
    location: string;
    weight: number;
    count: number;
    late: number;

    stock?: Stock[];

    constructor(data?: any) {
        console.debug('test', data);
        this.code = 'test';
        if (data) {
            this.code = data.code;
            this.location = data.location;
            this.weight = data.weight;
            this.count = data.count;
            this.late = data.late;
        }
    }
}
```

So just a copy of the values, but the weird thing is, it already errors on the `this.code = 'test'` then I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'code' of undefined
    at Warehouse (main.bundle.js:2218:19)
    at Array.map (native)
```

Any clue why this is happening?

Sample data:

```
[
  {
    "code": "SQD",
    "location": "35,16161;6,31561",
    "weight": 3200,
    "count": 18,
    "late": 18
  },
  {
    "code": "GQZ",
    "location": "35,16161;6,31561",
    "weight": 321,
    "count": 20,
    "late": 18
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share sample `data`? Also I guess issue is with `this` and not with `data`

Comment: yea, the problem lies with the 'this', that's why I did the `this.code = 'test'`, which failed

Comment: In my understanding, you will have to so something like `.map(x=>new Warehouse(x))`

Comment: I think since you are passing in a constructor, not an object, `this` doesn't exist in that context.

Comment: Your map simply calls warehouse, you need to construct a new Object using new Warehouse

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: If you had used an actual ES6 environment and not a sloppy transpiler, you'd get a proper error message that `class` constructors need to be called with `new`. `map` doesn't do that.

Comment: @Rajesh yep that did it, will you reply so I can accept? :)

Comment: @Kiwi Its alright! Glad, I was able to help! If you need any clarification, please tag

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be passing a constructor into the array map function, which is probably not what you want

```
def.resolve(r.data.map(Warehouse));
```

should probably be

```
def.resolve(new Warehouse(r.data));
```

the function r.data.map(FN) takes a function and returns an array that results from taking each element E of r.data and calling the function with E as the parameter, as in FN(E). see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: i made an assumption that you don't need the map function at all since your constructor is essentially expecting a data obj and already does the deep copy within.

Comment: This isn't what I want, beacuse I want each of the `r.data` to be of type Warehouse ;)

Comment: in that case Rajesh's comment is probably what you want